# Mount Google Drive from AI Platform Notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

Is there a way to mount Google My Drive from Google's AI Platform Notebook like Google Colab?

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use Python package gdrivefs to mount Google Drive to AI Platform Notebook. You can find exact information for setup from PyPi project page here: https://pypi.org/project/gdrivefs/.

To install in AI Platform Notebook you need to either install it at terminal or use shell commands in Notebook. With the following commands you should be able to do it:

Install dependencies and gdrivefs package:

```
!sudo apt-get install -y build-essential python-dev
!pip install gdrivefs
```

Authenticate to your Google Drive with the link provided from first command and pass the auth token to the second command:

```
!gdfstool auth_get_url
!gdfstool auth_write "xxx….”
```

Mount and list files. You should see Google Drive content:

```
!gdfs -o allow_other default /mnt/gdrivefs
!ls /mnt/gdrivefs
```

Now you can use the mounted files as local files:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/mnt/gdrivefs/mydata.csv')
print(df)
```

If I recall correctly the performance with this method is not very good. This works at least for temporary access, small data and copying data to more suited location.

To do the same in CoLab you need only the following code. It is much simpler and more performant but unfortunately `google.colab` does not work in AI Platform Notebook:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/mnt/drive')
```

Comment: For me, this failed at step: `!gdfs -o allow_other default /mnt/gdrivefs` Is there an update to these instructions? I'm on gcp ai platform notebooks tensorflow:2.5

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. The error is this: 
`fuse: bad mount point '/mnt/gdrivefs': No such file or directory`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/gdfs", line 76, in <module>
    _main()
  File "/opt/conda/bin/gdfs", line 73, in _main
    option_string=option_string)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gdrivefs/gdfuse.py", line 924, in mount
    **fuse_opts)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fuse.py", line 711, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError(err)
RuntimeError: 1`

Comment: If you have any insights on that, please let me know. If it needs more definition, I can perhaps submit a new question? Thanks!

Comment: My instructions seems to assume the mount directory already exists. Please make sure /mnt/gdrivefs exists by running !sudo mkdir /mnt/gdrivefs before gdfs command.

Comment: Thank you. (and I upvoted). I got some permissions/ownership issues doing this, but I ended up making a couple modifications which I'll detail in a supplementary answer for anyone else with my issue below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Veikko for his answer. I needed a slight modification. After the authentication step, I needed to create a *local* mount directory:

```sh
mkdir mnt/gdrivefs/
```

(There were permissions/ownership errors later if I created it in root). Next, I needed to modify the `/etc/fuse.conf` file to allow non-root users to specify mount options:

`sudo nano /etc/fuse.conf` and uncomment the line: `user_allow_other`

Then I ran the final steps (to the local `mnt/gdrivefs` dir) and everything worked:

```sh
!gdfs -o allow_other default mnt/gdrivefs
!ls mnt/gdrivefs
```

Comment: Hi @TC. Thanks for the instruction but I'm still stuck sadly. Please find following link to the snapshot from terminal within Vertex AI Workbench Jupyterlab notebook. Thanks in advance.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-3A0TSIc_e7JUDxJNK88k6tuzUTrdjAH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The very first line of the error message says "fusermount: user has no write access to mountpoint /mnt/drivefs". This tells me that you don't have sufficient permissions to access this drive. In a jupyter notebook cell, try the following unix command: `! chmod 777 /mnt/gdrivefs`. Does it work now?

Comment: Thanks @TC for your reply. Sorry but I have deleted everything and started all over again. Now the problem is [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UghNVhKwaIhegkuayNVhkKJJYOgCpHuU/view?usp=sharing). I don't understand what is this directory for?

Comment: Try `mkdir -p mnt/gdrivefs` . Then continue the instructions, changing permissions if needed in my comment. If that doesn’t work it might be a difference in something they changed between AI Platform notebook and Vertex AI in which case you might make a new question

Comment: Thanks a lot @TC! It works finally! I can now see the content in my Google Drive! =)